Conditional Rendering Issue with Redirects in React Native Expo using useContext
I have a simple app with an index.tsx file and a layout under "/app". I also have an auth context. If I leave both redirects here in index.tsx, the console log always gives me null and rendering happens only once. Otherwise, if I remove them, I get the log even when it succeeds and the user is loaded.
import React, { type ReactNode } from "react";
import { useAuthContext } from "@/contexts/AuthContext";
import { Redirect } from "expo-router";
import { Role } from "@/types/auth";

const Page = (): ReactNode => {
  const { status, user } = useAuthContext();
  console.log(status, user);

  if (user?.role.id === Role.Business) return <Redirect href={"/(business)"} />;

  return <Redirect href={"/(user)"} />;
};

export default Page;

in particular, I expect that when the user value is assigned in the context (logged in user) then it will render index.tsx again with the new value. this happens but only if I don't have both redirection inside index.tsx. if I put an empty normal stack it is rendered to me twice, the first with null because it is in pending status, the second success with the value of the user.

Do you need both redirects? Why not return <Redirect href={user?.role.id === Role.Business ? "/(business)" : "/(user)"} />;? Can you [edit] to clarify the problem, reproduction steps, and expected behavior vs current behavior?

It's confused to understand your question, What's suppose to happen?

ok the single redirect. but the problem persists I have updated the post with more details.

Please [edit] to provide us a complete [mcve] so we can see how this Page component is rendered and where/how it could be affected by the auth context.

I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish: get the current auth state and re-render if it changes with the new value or state. I don't quite understand the context of your question, but return <Redirect href={"/({})"} is being returned twice or affecting each other because of the order of operations when the value is passed causing redirect to execute asynchronously. Maybe try a conditional (ternary) operator: return user?.role.id === Role.Business ? <Redirect href={"/(business)"} : <Redirect href={"/(user)"} />;
